# Can I replace NSSet with NSArray in an NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmanagedobject, nsset

In a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, "To Many" relationships are generated as an `NSSet`. However I need the objects in the collection to be in a correct order, is there any potential errors if I replace `NSSet` with `NSArray`? Or is there any other ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your relationship as ordered in the object model designer, and then generate your subclass. It will have an `NSOrderedSet` as the class of the property for your to-many relationship, which you can use for similar purposes as an `NSArray`. Get familiar with the differences between the two before you proceed.

Comment: Thanks very much. Actually there is no "indexed" option in the relationships. There is an option "ordered". The problem is solved and thanks again.